# Is it possible to rewind a file descriptor cursor in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is what I would do in a perfect world:

```
fs.open('somepath', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
    fs.write(fd, 'somedata', function(err, written, string) {
       fs.rewind(fd, 0) //this doesn't exist
    })
})
```

This is my current implementation:

```
return async.waterfall([
    function(next) {
      //opening a file descriptor to write some data
      return fs.open('somepath', 'w+', next)
    }, 
    function(fd, next) {
      //writing the data
      return fs.write(fd, 'somedata', function(err, written, string) {
        return next(null, fd)
      })
    },
    function(fd, next) {
      //closing the file descriptor
      return fs.close(fd, next)
    },
    function(next) {
      //open again to reset cursor position
      return fs.open('somepath', 'r', next)
    }
], function(err, fd) { 
   //fd cursor is now at beginning of the file 
})
```

I tried to reset the position without closing the `fd` by using:

```
fs.read(fd, new Buffer(0), 0, 0, 0, fn)
```

but this throws `Error: Offset is out of bounds`.

Is there a way to reset the cursor without doing this horrible *hack*?

/e: The offset is out of bounds error comes from [this exception](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/29449349da5ef7e23689396c21bae003d81e0081/src/node_file.cc#L962). Easily fixed by setting a buffer size to 1 but it does not rewind the cursor. Maybe because we ask the function to read nothing.

Comment: Why do not you use the argument "position" functions read / write?

Comment: I don't need them, I'm using [this function](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_data_position_encoding_callback) to write and `position` argument is optional. I just want to write some data in a file and get back a file descriptor with a cursor at position 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, the answer is that it's not in the core, and that it can't be added with pure javascript.

There is an extension [node-fs-ext](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext) that adds a `seek` function to move the fd cursor. This is done in C++ [here](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext/blob/20c8190e3fedcc159f5c0449fa31220796fb7016/fs-ext.cc#L179).

Related [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855186/seek-equivalent-in-javascript-node-js).

Comment: fs-ext appears to be broken under v4.1.1.

Comment: Indeed, and it [won't work with 4.0 either](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext/issues/51). I'm still using my workaround.

Comment: After further investigation and talking with the maintainer, the problem is with Nan2.0 (which has changed considerably under v4.0+). The repo has been branched to support this and can be installed with npm directly from github until the changes are merged back to mainline. `npm install -g git+https://github.com/ggreer/node-fs-ext.git#nan_2`

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS v6.5.0 has the [createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) method which accepts an array of options. Among those options are the `start` and `end` properties. These properties determine **from** and **to** which byte should be read, respectively.

So, if you set `start` to `0`, it will read the file from the first byte. Leaving `end` empty in that case will cause the stream to read the file all the way to the end.

As an example:

```
fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt', {start: 0})
```

Using this read stream would allow you to read the whole file.

Comment: This has nothing to do with streams but more about controlling the file cursor pointer. More specifically, it's a binding to [`lseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) (in fs-ext for example).

Comment: I agree. I would like to see a solution for this as well, but this has been my workaround for now.

Comment: `start` and `end` are byte offsets, not line number. Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Answer (score 0):

[fs.write](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_string_position_encoding_callback) might be helpful here:

1. `fs.open` to get fd
2. `fs.write(fd, string, position)`
3. `fs.close(fd)`